Cannot use remote-ssh
I have installed ssh extension Remote-SSH. However, I cannot use it. And I cannot find it on the side bar. How to solve it?
I have tried to re-install VSCode/Remote, or change another version, but still not work. Could you help me solve it?
The environment is Mac M3 pro, the version of VSCode is 1.91.0(Universion).

If you are helping for help, you should deliver more information about your problem. What is your setup? When does the error occurs? What is the error? Provide code of configuration, a picture etc.
